# Performance issue running a macro in Excel across two tables from external data sources

Tags: vba, excel, excel-external-data

On a worksheet I have two tables which are populated from two different external sources, one from db2 and the other SQL server.  Once the data in the tables are refreshed I trigger a macro which runs VBA code that loops through the cells in both tables and applies business rules.

Testing it locally it works as expected and the macro completes in seconds.  When I change the connections to point to db2 and SQL server databases on the network, it refreshes the data in a timely manner, but when I trigger the macro it takes approx. 30 minutes to complete.  Only the connections have been changed and I'm using the same workbook for all testing.

First thought was that it is now pulling data from the network and it could be connectivity, but it refreshes the data OK and its only the macro that runs slowly and the VBA code does not use the connections and is just a basic for loop.

I'm lost to what is causing this and wanted to know if anyone has encountered this behaviour before and knows how I could resolve it?

Comment: Are you dealing with the same volumes of data as in testing?  Is the data sorted differently?  Difficult to make suggestions to improve your existing code unless you post it here...

Comment: Its approximately 40,000 rows in the first table and 50,000 in the second and each table has 5 columns.  They are sorted by ID.

Comment: That doesn't really answer either of my questions ;-)

Comment: as @TimWilliams said, please post your code. Also, are there calculations in the workbook that are being re-calced all the time during the code execution?

Comment: Is the local data you used for the initial tests the same data you load from the remote databases?  It seems likely the remote data is more complicated to process.  Have you tried adding code to calculate where the time is going?

Comment: Its the same data on the local databases as it is on the remote databases.  I've added the code.  There is only the tables and this code in the workbook.  I have tried following the IDs to see if one in particular slows it down but all looks like it runs at the same speed.  I could look at timings at each step.  Just baffled to why it doesn't cause a problem on the local database if its the code and why if it is the remote connection why it is causing a problem when I run the code and not the refresh of the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the issue.

Someone had changed the view that populates the table in one database to use the LEFT function which turned a number into a string in the worksheet.  So looked like comparing the string in one table to the number in the other caused the performance issue.

Surprised it caused it to slow so much, but casting it back to an integer makes it work correctly again.

Thanks for helping